# how to print only adf table having pagination and which is displaying from collection

Tags: jsf, oracle-adf

```
I have a adf table which is displaying from collection and there is a command button like PRINT.
           <af:commandButton text="Print"
                            binding="#{backingBeanScope.backing_ReportHealthCheck.cb2}"
                            id="cb2">
            <af:showPrintablePageBehavior/>
          </af:commandButton>
```

I'm using above code but it is displaying whole page. My requirement is when i click on that button, i need only adf table whole contents from the jsff, which is having Pagination.Print option may be like normal print option we will get while printing some application.Will anyone post source code for this requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where is the button in relation to the table?
Try to put the button in the toolbar part of a panelCollection that surrounds the table.